# vt-x - virtualization technology

Tags: windows-10

please help. In my laptop( hp probook 4530s) bios it is enabled with the name of virtualization technology but it does not allow me to enable this option hyper - v in windows in program and feature option as it give me the message that hyper-v cannot be installed: virtualization support is disabled in firmware.

Comment: Does your CPU support it?

Comment: how can confirm this. in bios there is a option given which I enabled it.

Comment: Look up your CPU

Comment: how and where can look it.

Comment: can we discuss this on skype or viber.

Comment: Of course we cannot.  If I helped you in private nobody else who had your problem would get help.

Comment: what and where i look up my CPU

Comment: @rehmanpanjwani open run (Win+R keys), type msinfo32 and click ok. On that page there will be a Procesor item, can you let us know what that says. We can then let you know if the CPU supports it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your hp probook 4530 is the standard specs for your model then you have an intel Core i5-2410m.

Intel lists this chip as having VT-X, one of the prerequisites for hyper-V.
Microsoft provides a [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/quick_start/walkthrough_compatibility) for hyper-v support.

The summary is:

- 64 bit processor with Second level address translation
- VT-C for intel
- 4GB ram
- BIOS Enable Virtualization technology & Hardware enforced data execution prevention.
- Windows Professional or higher

You can check if your system is hyper-v ready by running cmd prompt and typing systeminfo.exe. At the bottom there will be a Hyper-V section and it will inform you if you have all the settings enabled.